# Custom Toolbar placed in the NavigationBar Shifting

Tags: iphone, ios, toolbar, navigationbar

I'm having a strange problem with my custom toolbar that is sometimes shifting slightly right:

I created a **UIView** subclass that contains 4 **UIButtons** and a **UIImageView**. 
I insert this component (custom toolbar) into the navigation bar of the view controller using the following line:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = toolbar;
```

This works fine: The buttons are actionable etc.

However, depending on the view controller that I am pushing (using the navigation controller) the custom toolbar shifts slight to right, just enough to crop a tiny part of the image view.

When I compare the view controller that has a stable toolbar with another one that's toolbar is shifting, I cannot see any different. And they are pushed at the same level in the navigation history. So I am really confused. I thought it was because of the presence of the **Back Button** but it is present in both views. I think the most confusing thing is to have a controller view that behaves correctly and another one that behaves consistently differently.

Any ideas, pointers, links will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Happy holiday season.